# add OLEObject in phpword

Tags: phpword, phpoffice

i'm trying to add OLE object using PHPWord sample
but no object is added

```
 <?php
 require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

  $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
  $section = $phpWord->addSection();
  $section->addText('You can open this OLE object by double clicking on the 
  icon:');
  $section->addTextBreak(2);
   $section->addOLEObject('resources/_sheet.xls');
```

PHP 5:
 PHPWord version: 0.14
windows7 ultimate sp1
MS Office 2010

Comment: what do you see instead? Nothing? Or nothing happens when you click the icon?

Comment: I don't even see the icon , no icon added

Comment: Is there any idea to help please

Comment: Even in version 0.16 this is broken. It will create an image but not properly embed the document. It has been broken for a long time.